# Python MIP unable to add Binary Variable vector

Tags: python-3.x, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to use the MIP package in python. I am using the code in the quick start guide (https://python-mip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) but it throws the following error for the binary variable:

```
m = Model(sense=MAXIMIZE, solver_name=GRB) # using gurobi instead of CBC

x = m.add_var()
n = 10
y = [ m.add_var(var_type=BINARY) for i in range(n) ]
```

```
  File "C:\Users\NAME\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mip\gurobi.py", line 454, in add_var
    name.encode("utf-8"),
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'char' must be a bytes of length 1, not bytes
```

the line corresponds to the last line on this function in gurobi.py but tbh I have no idea how this is breaking down

```
    def add_var(
        self,
        obj: float = 0,
        lb: float = 0,
        ub: float = INF,
        var_type: str = CONTINUOUS,
        column: Column = None,
        name: str = "",
    ):
        # collecting column data
        nz = 0 if column is None else len(column.constrs)
        if nz:
            self.flush_rows()
            vind = ffi.new("int[]", [c.idx for c in column.constrs])
            vval = ffi.new("double[]", [column.coeffs[i] for i in range(nz)])
        else:
            vind = ffi.NULL
            vval = ffi.NULL

        # variable type
        vtype = var_type.encode("utf-8")

        st = GRBaddvar(
            self._model,
            nz,
            vind,
            vval,
            obj,
            lb,
            ub,
            vtype,
            name.encode("utf-8"),
        )
```

Anyone know why? I'm pretty stumped if simply copying the quick start code is breaking down on me.

Comment: Which versions? Python, MIP, gurobi.

Comment: python 3.7.6, gurobi 9.1.2, mip '1.13.0'

Comment: Interesting. Sadly i don't know much about ctypes (where i expect things break), but the code looks fitting in regards to gurobis C-API. Did you try a non-anaconda based python? Not sure if that makes sense, but i'm somewhat puzzled by the error. ctypes is clearly setup with `const char *` and yet the error looks as it was setup with `(const) char`. I would have guessed a python 2 / 3 problem, but with your versions this is strange to me. Maybe add an issue to the github-tracker of the project if you got a fully working minimal example (aka running out of the box -> imports and such).

Comment: yeah its a strange one, the docs say minimum python 3.5 but I am using 3.7 so shouldn't be an issue. Will put it to the github then instead. thanks